# How to add a new GitHub organization to Travis?

Tags: github, travis-ci

As a GitHub user I have three public organizations, my own one in my name, and two others.  Several months ago I opened up Travis, looked around a bit and, apparently, added my three organizations.

A few days ago I created a 4th organization and have created several repos there, but now I find I cannot see that org in Travis.

I reviewed every setting available to an organization, comparing the connecting organizations with the one that won't connect, but found no difference.   In Webhooks & Services for each of the four repos, I added Travis as a Service, but it made no difference.

Is there a long delay? Is there a way to force a sync operation?

Where can I read the instructions for making a new org appear in Travis?

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My missing organization appeared over night.   So it seems to be due  simply to time-lapse topography.

Comment: I had the same problem, and I was wondering how long it would take. Even pushing the sync button didn't help. Turns out when I simply refreshed the browser my orgs appeared.